# How to save "syncfusion document editor" to database

Tags: syncfusion

[image: my screen]

I want to save the document editor provided by syncfusion but i'm not able to implement the save functionality. could anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Using [`SaveASBlob()`](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/document-editor/export/#export-as-blob) method you will get the Document as Blob stream(Docx format) in client side and you can save that stream in Database.
Below KB link contains how to save the document in APP_Data folder, you can customize it based on your requirement.

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10304/how-to-load-save-file-in-web-server-for-asp-net-core